# How do I code Cookie Yes to let me display on certain countries

Tags: xcode, cookies, cookieyes

Is there a way to code Cookie Yes so only certain countries can see it? Because it's just not worth paying 200 a year just so certain people don't see it on my website.

Or is anyone willing to just share their account with me since they don't charge any more than what they have?

If you have an answer to either of those or if there is a better plugin for WordPress please email me at EtchifyEngraving@gmail.com

I didn't try anything because I couldn't find where I need to put the code.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask